# Facing Severe Buffering Issues in FFmpeg Pipeline for Simultaneous Video and Audio Live Streaming via SRT Protocol

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, cloudflare

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using FFmpeg to livestream via Cloudflare using the SRT protocol. My main goal is to make sure I can stream both video and audio at the same time. Things have been going well with video streaming, but I've run into a bit of a problem when it comes to adding audio to the mix.

The issue I'm facing is that when I try to connect the audio to the video stream, I'm having some serious buffering problems. The video with audio does work, but all that buffering is messing up the quality of the livestream.

I have a feeling the problem might have something to do with my FFmpeg pipeline, but I'm still pretty new to using FFmpeg. Could someone please lend a hand and help me figure out how to fix this buffering issue in my FFmpeg setup so I can livestream both video and audio at the same time? Any advice or suggestions you have would be a huge help.

Here's the code I'm using for my FFmpeg pipeline:

```
ffmpeg_stream = [
            "ffmpeg",
            "-re",
            "-flags", "+global_header",
            "-fflags", "+genpts",
            "-threads", "8",
            "-thread_queue_size", "1024",
            "-loglevel", "debug",
            "-f", "rawvideo",
            "-pix_fmt", "bgr24",
            "-s", "1280x720",
            "-i", "-",
            "-channel_layout", "mono",
            "-f", "alsa",
            "-thread_queue_size", "32768",
            "-ac", "1",
            "-i", "hw:4,0",
            "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
            "-c:v", "libx264",
            "-max_muxing_queue_size", "9999",
            "-b:v:0", "3000k",
            "-g", "25",
            "-c:a", "aac",
            "-ar", "44100",
            "-b:a", "128k",
            "-map", "0:v:0",
            "-map", "1:a:0",
            "-preset", "veryfast",
            "-tune", "zerolatency",
            "-f", "mpegts",
            my_srt_url
        ]
```

Let me know if any other info is needed. Thanks!